# Thunderbird message filters often don't work

Tags: thunderbird

Based on my experience [message filters](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/organize-your-messages-using-filters) generally don't work when several options in the same category are enabled:

[image: message filters]

I have to create a separate filter for every spam domain and unwanted keyword. The filters can't be executed manually by pressing `run now` and aren't run automatically as specified.  Is this a bug or limitation in Thunderbird and how can this issue be solved?

I have recently [compacted folders](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/compacting-folders).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have "Match all of the following" selected. This means that every one of the criteria you have set must be met for the message to be matched by the filter. In this case, every message checked MUST have a 'From' field that contains every value listed. Example: The From is 'a@b.com', your filter is checking if the From is 'a@b.com' and 'b@b.com' and 'c@b.com'. Since it is only 'a@b.com', the match fails because it does not also have b@b.com and c@b.com (criteria meaning ALL of the items in the list).

This filtering would be helpful if you wanted to match on a number of different fields (Such as From being from 'a@b.com' and Subject contains 'Dog', and putting them in one folder, but 'a@b.com' and Subject of 'Cat' going to a different folder)

You probably want "Match any of the following". This will test to see if one or more of the criteria are met for the message to be matched by the filter.
Example: The From is 'a@b.com', your filter is checking if the From is 'a@b.com' or 'b@b.com' or 'c@b.com', the match succeeds because 'a@b.com' is found. (criteria meaning any one of the items).

This filtering would be useful when you have one field that could be any value that you want to match to qualify (like spam / junk filtering).

Comment: It seems that I have confused "match any of the following"/"match all of the following".